# python's docopt treats command like a parameter with itself as a value

Tags: python, docopt

My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""
Usage:
  mymodule foobar   [options]
  mymodule WOS      [options]

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen
  -f --force-update        Re-scan downloaded issues in plot mode

"""
import docopt

if __name__=='__main__':

    # Parse arguments, use file docstring as a parameter definition
    arguments = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    print(arguments)
```

and I save the above as `mymodule.py` and then run `mymodule.py WOS`. The output is

```
{'--force-update': False,
 '--help': False,
 'WOS': 'WOS',
 'foobar': False}
```

That's not right!  The value of `WOS` should be `True`, not "WOS" !
I use docopt heavily and have for years. Am I too tired, or is this a new bug?

Comment: A word that is all uppercase is interpreted as an argument by docopt, not as a command https://github.com/docopt/docopt#usage-pattern-format

Comment: @IainShelvington Argh. Honestly, I did try to read the docs.  Do you want to write the answer? Or should I just delete this question?  Thanks